# Pasar el Header a Dropzone - laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, dropzone

Hola tengo una duda de como poder pasarle el Token a mi Dropzone.

normalmente lo hacía así desde una vista de laravel. Agregando Js. en ella misma. Y no había problema.

```html
var myDropZone = new Dropzone('.dropzone',{

   url: '/admin/posts/{{$post->url}}/photos',
   paramName:'photo', 
   acceptedFiles:'image/*', 
   maxFilesSize: 2,
   maxFiles: 10,//
   dictDefaultMessage:'Arrastra las fotos aqui para subirlas',
   headers:{
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN':'{{ csrf_token()}}'
   }
  });
```

pero ahora,  Estoy  con Vue.  ese fue el que descargue.

```html
npm install vue2-dropzone
```

pero lo que pasa es que donde estoy intentando cargar una imagen, Es que estoy desde un componente Vue.

Y no sé como pasarle ese token al componente.
...
Estoy haciendo un SPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca he usado `vue2-dropzone` pero [según la documentación](https://rowanwins.github.io/vue-dropzone/docs/dist/index.html#/props), la propiedad (prop) `options` acepta lo mismo que las [opciones de dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration-options).

Ya que tienes opciones dinámicas (la url y el token del header), tienes que hacerlo usando [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html):

```
import vue2Dropzone from 'vue2-dropzone';
import 'vue2-dropzone/dist/vue2Dropzone.min.css'


export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    vueDropzone: vue2Dropzone
  },
  data() {
    return {
      id:'dropZone'
    }
  },
  computed: {

    postUrl() {
       // aquí obtienes lo que para ti era $post->url, 
       let thePostUrl = getPostUrl(); // nombre cualquiera para obtenerlo
       return thePostUrl;
    },
    url() {
       return `/admin/posts/${this.postUrl}/photos`;
    },
    token() {
        // aquí obtienes el token csrfToken
        let csrfToken = getToken(); // la manera como obtenías el token
        return csrfToken:
    },
    headers() {
        return {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': this->token };
    },
    dropzoneOpts() {
       return {
          // se obtiene de la propiedad computed url
          url: this.url, 
          paramName:'photo', 
          acceptedFiles:'image/*', 
          maxFilesSize: 2,
          maxFiles: 10,
          dictDefaultMessage:'Arrastra las fotos aqui para subirlas',
          // se obtiene de la propiedad computed headers 
          headers: this.headers
       };
    }
  }
}
```

Y en la plantilla:

```
<vue-dropzone ref="myDropzone" :id="id" :options="dropzoneOpts"></vue-dropzone>
```

Comment: me diste una idea de como  pasarle el token: Lo puse así:

  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

Comment: Hay un proverbio chino que dice: "Si no está roto, no lo arregles". Esa solución crea un acoplamiento innecesario entre el componente y su plantilla, pero probablemente sea irrelevante para este caso de uso. Tal vez sería menos arriesgado usar `$(this.el).find(('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') ` para no arriesgarte a que otra instancia de dropzone ensucie a la primera.